# How to use array in select query where statement in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have code like this:

```
$sql11 = "select room_no from guestrocordtransc where roomtype='".$roomtype."'";
$retval11 = mysql_query( $sql11, $conn );
while($row11 = mysql_fetch_array($retval11,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{ 
    $cid_room=$row11['roomno']; 
}
```

Here I'm getting an array of room numbers, which is stored in `$cid_room`.

Now, I need this `$cid_room` in select query to fetch a particular room_no which is not in `guestrocordtransac`.

My second query looks like this:

```
$sql = "select room_no 
FROM roominfo WHERE room_no 
NOT IN(
select roomno 
from guestrocordtransac 
where roomtype='".$roomtype."' 
between '".$check_in."' 
and '".$check_out."' 
and cid='".$cid_room."') 
and roomtype='".$roomtype."'";
```

Is it possible to give the array value (`$cid_room`) like this in query, will it check all the value.

Comment: Don't use mysql_* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: do you mean: WHERE room_no !=  $cid_room AND roomtype='".$roomtype."'"; ???

Comment: rooinfo table is like this: id,room_no,roomtype,cid .......for eg:(1st row) 1      302       a/c         1....(2nd row)2      201       non_a/c            2.....I hope you understand

Comment: My comment is not related to your question. it is a offer for the security of your code

Answer (score 1):

if $cid_room is not a multi-dimensional array, you **use array in select query** like that:

`"SELECT room_no FROM roominfo 
WHERE room_no NOT IN (".implode(',',$cid_room).") 
AND roomtype='".$roomtype."'";`

But I ' m not sure that works in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the array to an `IN()` clause.

```
$in = '(';
foreach($cid_room as $num){
  $in.= "'$num',"
}
$in = substr($sql,0,-1) . ') ';  // remove trailing comma and close
```

Answer (score 0):

1:  `while($row11 = mysql_fetch_array($retval11,MYSQL_ASSOC))
    { 
        $cid_room=$row11['roomno']; 
    }`

by this u are not getting a array of `$cid_room`

u have to use `$cid_room[]` instead of $cid_room

2. `$sql = "select room_no 
   FROM roominfo WHERE room_no 
   NOT IN(
   select roomno 
   from guestrocordtransac 
   where roomtype='".$roomtype."' 
   between '".$check_in."' 
   and '".$check_out."' 
   and cid in '".$cid_room."') 
   and roomtype='".$roomtype."'";`